# MSBuild, Xamarin.Forms, Continuous Integration, iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, msbuild, continuous-integration

I'm starting to work on setting up CI/CD for a Xamarin.Forms project I'm working on. Currently I'm setting up the Ad-Hoc config. I'd like to be able to run this build from the command line, and get the IPA in my bin/AdHoc folder like if I were to run it from within Visual Studio.

I've tried all sorts of combinations of different things. Here's how I'm triggering the build:

```
msbuild ../TheSolution.sln /p:Configuration=Ad-Hoc /p:Platform=iPhone /p:ServerAddress=serverIP /p:ServerUser=%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME% /p:ServerPassword=myPassword
```

In the project file, in addition to the Provisioning Profile info, within this configuration's property group, I have

```
<BuildIpa>True</BuildIpa>
<IpaPackageDir>$(OutputPath)</IpaPackageDir>
```

I've tried no domain on username, different cases, /m flag to build.

At best I've gotten an intermittent connection to the mac, but it has mostly been failing. Same credentials, same mac, same solution generates the IPA if I build from within Visual Studio. What am I missing here?

Comment: AppCenter will do this for free with much less headache than setting up your own

Comment: @Jason Unfortunately AppCenter is not an option for build, my company has an on site BitBucket server for Git repos, to my knowledge I can't hook AppCenter up to it. Thank you though.

Comment: you can use a 2nd remote git repo that is sync'd to your on premise repo, and drive app center from that

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll bring this up as an option if I can't get tools working like intended. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried running it *on* the mac instead of running it remotely?

Comment: @valdetero No, I haven't. However, when I build from within Visual Studio I'm not running it on the mac either. I was hoping for a simple command line solution here. The next step will be to set up a mac as a build agent through Bamboo and execute a build on the mac itself. The command line should be possible, right?

Comment: Theoretically that should work, but it seemed too iffy to me. I just run mine directly on the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

In looking at diagnostic build output between what Visual Studio was outputting and what my script was outputting, I realized that I needed to escape some characters in my password. I just ran a successful command line build using (From a PS script):

```
Invoke-MsBuild -Path "..\TheSolution.sln" -MsBuildParameters "/target:Clean;Build /property:Configuration=Ad-Hoc;Platform=iPhone;ServerAddress=serverip;ServerUser=usernamenodomain;ServerPassword=escapedpw;ContinueOnDisconnected=false /verbosity:Diagnostic"
```